# example of javascript's eval not being evil?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I read some stackOverflow questions and answers more then ten times per day, and... it looks its first time i feel its okey to post something, as i didnt find accurate enought answer.

Im writing some code in nodeJS. Its web interface for big softswitch based on custom asterisk, where in one place i need to get data from post message from website.

The problem is, that that post message containts numerous info named in fashion:

> peer1
>
> peer2
>
> peer3
>
> peer4 etc

Instead of dealing with every single one,  i did a loop:

```
 var array = [];
 var i = 0;
        while (typeof eval("req.body.peer" + i) !== 'undefined' &&  eval("req.body.peer" + i) !== '') {
        console.log('petla wisielca');
        //console.log(eval("req.body.peer" + i));
        array.push(eval('req.body.peer' + i));
        i++;
        }
```

Number filled inputs (actually its html select) is variable.

After creating that array, I deal with rest of things (write peers to file etc) in traditional, non-eval loops.

Am i missing something here, or it's proper way of dealing with such situation?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Looks like i had some kind brain malfunction :).

Solution is very easy,

as [kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030802/kyle-robinson-young) cleared it out, to access object variables and for example iterate, all is needed is to use [].

**Solution:**

```
var array = []
var i = 0
while (req.body['peer' + i]) {
  array.push(req.body['peer' + i])
  i++
}
```

Thanks once more Kyle.

Comment: Why do you even need eval() for that ?

Comment: So you're asking how to use a variable as a property name? It surprises me that you couldn't find an answer, since that question is asked frequently.

Comment: Square bracket notation to the rescue. `req.body["peer" + i]`

Comment: ...and note that this isn't an "evil" use of `eval`, but it's an unfortunate use as it's entirely unnecessary and can have weighty performance implications.

Comment: Constructing variable names dynamically often is just a consequence of code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript objects can be accessed like they're associative arrays:

```
var array = []
var i = 0
while (req.body['peer' + i]) {
  array.push(req.body['peer' + i])
  i++
}
```

Comment: Of course! I have no idea why i didnt use solution i use whole time everywhere around...

somehow i totally forgot that i can do +i inside of []...

sorry for unnecessary question (for rest of people at least). it's my 10th our of coding. thank You anyway for clearing brain-blackout :)

Answer (score 1):

Use of eval is ever evitable, i wrote a plugin that make some dynamic calls of functions, you can check how you can access the object without using eval:

https://github.com/HaSuKrOnOs/jquery-dynFn